# import database from txt file into mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to import data of my data base into txt file and after that I want to export it again from this text file I wrote this code

```
private void importdata() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone = UTC", "root", "");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Tools.msg(ex.getMessage());
        }
        String csvFilePath = "D://t1.txt";
        try {
            String sql = "select ID,address,name from t1";
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(csvFilePath);
            OutputStreamWriter fileWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            fileWriter.write("ID,Name,address");
            while (rs.next()) {
                int ID = rs.getInt("id");
                String Name = rs.getString("name");
                String address = rs.getString("address");
                String line;
                line = String.format("%s,%s,%s",
                        ID,address,Name);
                fileWriter.write("\n");
                fileWriter.write(line);
            }
            stmt.close();
            fileWriter.close();

        } catch (SQLException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(importandexport.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=true characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone = UTC", "root", "");
            String sql = "delete from t1";
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Tools.msg(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void export() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone = UTC", "root", "");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Tools.msg(ex.getMessage());
        }        
        String sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE 'D://t1.txt' \n"
                + "INTO TABLE t1 \n"
                + "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' \n"
                + "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'\n"
                + " IGNORE 1 ROWS";
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Tools.msg(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

this code works well for me but now I want to I want to select (ID,name,address) and load (ID,name,address) instead of (ID,address,name) but I couldn't do that, so How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Mate your question is kind of vague, and try not post long codes in your question...
Attempt things by your own and post questions when you get stuck somewhere.

And about your issue, this may be what you wanna do:

```
                ...
                String line;
                line = String.format("%s,%s,%s",
                        ID,Name,address); //instead of ID,address,Name
                fileWriter.write("\n");
                fileWriter.write(line);
                ...
```

Comment: but when I'll export my data again it won't export correctly because in database there are (ID,address,Name)

Comment: What do you mean when you say export? Insert the records back into the DB? The order of columns in your tables doesn't really matter. You can retrieve the data in any column order that you want, by using the select query. And if at all you wanna change the column position of MySQL table, you should run this SQL query: ```ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY Name varchar(200) AFTER Address;```